# MacBook Retina Mid-2012 Mojave 3500RPM Fans on Idle

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, ssd, performance

I am having some issues with a Macbook Pro Retina Mid-2012, Running Mojave due to needing 32-bit support for a variety of applications.

First off, It is running an Original Samsung 768GB Apple SSD, which was about a $1000 upgrade to the first MacBook Retina Mid-2012 Model. Here is the Smart Stats on the Drive, a lofty 24,000 hours or so.

It seems to have some indication of Wear Leveling but nothing specific, and of course, is useless information to me to resolve the issue I am having which is general slowness, and kernel_task throttling back the cpu, and the fans being 3500 RPM at Idle. (Supposed to be 1500-2000).

EtreeCheck suggests the SSD is Slow, But not failing.

[image: Drive DX]

To ensure it was not suffering from slowness caused by the well-known Security Update-005 Mojave / Safari 14.x.x Issues which cause the same symptom, I performed the step of reinstalling Mojave in-place, and testing without performing the updates and everything was the same way: High Idle, bad multitasking, choppy graphics performance.

I have made updates to all available applications, and have seen an improvement in some performance metrics but only when the machine is not loaded. As soon as I put a professional, heavy demand on the machine, it is a bad experience and an extreme test of patience. I can't really develop, game, or power-use anymore, But for most of this machines 10+ year life, it has been an extreme performer so I'm not sure what is going on.

Before throwing money at it with an OWC SSD which I am thinking of buying to replace the OEM SSD in an attempt to solve the problem, I would like to know what the community suggests beyond what I have done. Note, a clean install seems to be no different under load. Processors aren't hitting 90C, So I am not sure why they would be throttling so hard.

The MBP has a revised logic board from Apple, replaced under an extended recall warranty due to faulty circuit board / Nvidia GPU failing from the package. Sensors when idling look like this:

[image: iStat Sensors]

[image: iStat CPU]

As you can see system load average is always above 1.5 average. Should be around 1.0 Idle.

EtreeCheck for a few consecutive reports was telling me that SSD Performance was low, I freed up 300GB of the 750GB Apple SSD hoping this would help, and it did, I no longer recieve a notice that the performance for SSD is low, Though compared to a NVMe SSD they would seem low! (420mb Write, 470mb Read.) but thats about what this old SSD is supposed to be doing so It would seem this old drive is still good? I am not sure.

Performance:
System Load: 1.76 (1 min ago) 1.44 (5 min ago) 1.71 (15 min ago)
Nominal I/O usage: 0.04 MB/s
File system: 21.13 seconds
Write speed: 415 MB/s
Read speed: 467 MB/s

If I try playing any Steam or Blizzard Games, or demanding multitasking such as opening 100 Tabs in Firefox, the system crawls to a halt, with fans spinning at 5000RPM, and Kernel task taking up 400%+ of the CPU on average.

Bonus Question: Is it even worth spending the cost of a 2TB OWC SSD ($400 USD), Assuming this old hardware will last that long? I guess that's for me to decide, but I am having a tough time even though I have 2 of these machines, One has a damaged Screen and a newer revised logic board, and I use it as a spare incase my primary fails, which has a more original logic board that has occasional flickers when switching between the GPUs on the Retina Display. (I expect it is likely because the GPU Die is slightly defective and detaching.)

This is my first post here, Feel free to ask me for any other information I could provide that may be of further diagnostic value.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the drive is responsible for high fan usage and poor performance. TBH, if you're looking for developing, games and other pro use, then I'd suggest putting the $400 towards a new model.

Comment: I appreciate the response,
I have made a current backup, in the event that the SSD suddenly fails catastrophically as did the other same SSD in the same MacBook I have as a spare. I will put the money to better use....

Note: I cleaned out the dust from the machine and it is throttling significantly less, In fact, almost not at all. But graphics performance (Via Nvidia Geforce 650M) seems to be choppy when under load, under the current OS Mojave. I think the biggest contributing step to fixing this issue here was freeing up space on the Internal SSD (As it was running with Less than 5GB).